# Autoscale WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Has a program written in a notebook with a resolution of 1600x900, all the elements are placed normally, and the same program on a monitor with 1920x1080 scale from 125% windows are placed incorrectly. How on WinForms c# consider it and how to redraw?

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider using the anchor and Dock properties this is how you position your controls on the form and control their positions in various scales

you can find here very useful article about using 
[anchoring and docking](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/#.)

Answer (score 1):

By making use of anchors and docks then you should be able to create a WinForm which scales to any size monitor.

It would be helpful if you could edit your question and include the designer code so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the form resize as you want, You can use table layout panels to set your layout and then you can use the anchor property of the controls to set, where they should move when the form is resized.

The anchor property simply anchors the control to a location, for example if you anchor a text box to may be left, then on resize it will be at left. Or if you anchor it to say both left and right, if will expand in both directions. Just explore them and it should work fine for you.